# Is it possible to bypass a relay SSH server?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

Is it possible to tell SSH to initiate a direct connection from a machine to another when the connection is passing through an intermediate SSH server ?
I would like to do this to avoid the latency of the connection to be the sum of the latencies of the two tunnels.

Currently I have a SSH reverse tunnel from machine1 to machine2, because machine1 doesn't accept incoming connections, and only machine2 have a static IP.
In order to access machine1 from machine3, the connection is passing via 2 tunnels, one from machine3 to machine2, and another from machine2 to machine1.

When I am connected, I would like the connection to switch from an indirect connection to a direct connection.

NOTE : I don't want machine3 to have an SSH server, only a client

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

SSH doesn't natively support setting up a port forward on a machine. It could be done with a custom script that configures the OS to forward packets from machine3's IP to machine1, and back. I would advice against the custom port forwarding method because it lack security, namely it vulnerable to IP spoofing, and properly also other problems.